# execute curl command inside php script and get response from server and extract it

Tags: php, android, curl, paypal, command

I want to verify the proof of android paypal payment
to do that, I want to execute this code :

```
    curl https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/PaymentDetails \
 -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: user_id" \
 -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: password" \
 -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: signature" \
 -H "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV" \
 -H "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV" \
 -H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-91B933855X481767M" \
 -d "payKey=AP-70M68096ML426802W&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US"
```

since I am just a beginner in php, how can I run this command in php script and receive a response

can you link me to some examples also

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$http_header = array(
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: user_id",
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: password",
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: signature",
    "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV",
    "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV",
    "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-91B933855X481767M"
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/PaymentDetails");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $http_header );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "payKey=AP-70M68096ML426802W&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, true);

$html = curl_exec ($ch);
echo $html;
```

Comment: thank youit works, but I have this error  :   Notice: curl_setopt(): CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST no longer accepts the value 1, value 2 will be used instead  in this line :  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, true);